# XSLT dynamic element selection

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm looking to dynamically print out elements which exist in a control list using only native XSLT2.0 functions.

```
<xsl:variable name="controlList">name</xsl:variable>

<M N="name" V="Bill Billson"/>
<M N="address" V="1234 street name"/>
<M N="country" V="United Kingdom"/>
<M N="phone" V="123456789"/>
```

Output Required:

```
Bill Billson
```

Ultimately however it will need to cope with multiple values in the control list e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="controlList">name,address,phone</xsl:variable>
```

So far i have tried many different permutations but not getting the required results.

```
<xsl:value-of select="M[@N='{$controlList}']/@V"/>
```

or

```
  <xsl:for-each select="M">
        <xsl:value-of select="/[@name=$controlList]/@V"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This may not even be available with native XSLT2.0 functions

Comment: I am trying to further extend this, by passing in first a label to be printed out, and secondly the name of the field to get the value from, is this possible? e.g controllist would be 'Full Name,name,Home Address,address, Mobile Number,phone'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variable as `<xsl:variable name="controlList" select="'name', 'address', 'phone'"/>`, then yo can use `M[@N = $controlList]/@V`. See http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKw1 for an example.

If you can't set up the first variable as a sequence of strings then compute a second e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="controlList">name,address,phone</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="controlSeq" select="tokenize($controlList, ',')"/>
```

and then you can also make the `=` comparison in

```
<xsl:value-of select="M[@N = $controlSeq]/@V"/>
```